# Change value of uneven to specific even numbers

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe with mixed data types and I would like to change the values of str cells (each consisting of two letters plus three numbers) so that uneven number become even numbers but the number decreases. AB123 should become AB122 while not changing the letter before it.

Here is an example dataframe with mixed types:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'Opportunity':['AB122','AB123','AB125', 'AB124'],
           'Quantity': [2, 3, 4, 1],
           'Member': ["AACC", "AACC", "AACC", 'DDEE']})


print (df)
  Opportunity  Quantity Member
0       AB122         2   AACC
1       AB123         3   AACC
2       AB121         4   AACC
3       AB120         1   DDEE
```

I would like the outcome to be:

```
print (df2)

  Opportunity  Quantity Member
0       AB122         2   AACC
1       AB122         3   AACC
2       AB120         4   AACC
3       AB120         1   DDEE
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try:

```
df['Opportunity'] = df['Opportunity'].str[:2] + np.where(df['Opportunity'].str[2:].astype(int) % 2, df['Opportunity'].str[2:].astype(int).sub(1).astype(str), df['Opportunity'].str[2:])
```

And now:

```
print(df)
```

Is:

```
  Member Opportunity  Quantity
0   AACC       AB122         2
1   AACC       AB122         3
2   AACC       AB120         4
3   DDEE       AB120         1
```

Answer (score 2):

Here's one way slicing with pandas's [`str`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.html) accessor, subtracting the [`mod`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.mod.html) by 2 to the integer part and concatenating back to the column using [`str.cat`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.cat.html):

```
d = df.Opportunity.str[-2:].astype(int)
df['Opportunity'] = df.Opportunity.str[:3].str.cat(d.sub(d.mod(2)).astype(str))

    Opportunity  Quantity Member
0       AB122         2   AACC
1       AB122         3   AACC
2       AB120         4   AACC
3       AB120         1   DDEE
```

---

Input dataframe:

```
print(df)

Opportunity  Quantity Member
0       AB122         2   AACC
1       AB123         3   AACC
2       AB121         4   AACC
3       AB120         1   DDEE
```

Comment: I think checking the last digit should be enough, so `...str[-1].astype(int)` and `...str[:-1].str.cat...` may be clearer.

Comment: That's a good point @AndyL. although I do use `d` later on to directly concatenate the first three characters, so I think I'll laeave it as is

Answer (score 0):

```
df['Opportunity'] = df.Opportunity.apply(lambda x: x[:-3]+str(int(x[-3:]) - 1) if int(x[-3:]) % 2 != 0 else x)
```

---

```
Opportunity  Quantity Member
0       AB122         2   AACC
1       AB122         3   AACC
2       AB120         4   AACC
3       AB120         1   DDEE
```

Answer (score 0):

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'Opportunity':['AB122','AB123','AB125', 'AB124'],
               'Quantity': [2, 3, 4, 1],
               'Member': ["AACC", "AACC", "AACC", 'DDEE']})

even = lambda x: int(x) % 2 == 0
df['Opportunity'] = df['Opportunity'].apply(lambda x: x[:2] + (x[2:] if even(x[2:]) else str(int(x[2:]) -1)))

print(df)
```

output:

```
  Opportunity  Quantity Member
0       AB122         2   AACC
1       AB122         3   AACC
2       AB124         4   AACC
3       AB124         1   DDEE
```